# How to detect if the device has sensor to use compass in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sensors, compass

There are some devices that doesn't have built-in sensor to use compass

what i am trying to do here is to navigate or show message to the user if the phone doesn't support this feature

i am trying this:

```
sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    if (sensor !== null) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }else{
        val intent = Intent(this, SetProfileActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

but get this error every time:

```
sensorManager.getDefault…(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) must not be null
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: still looking for an answer ..

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over the same problem.

This is the solution I found and works for me:

```kotlin
val pm: PackageManager = context.packageManager
if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS)) {
  // This device does not have a compass, turn off the compass feature
}
```